# How to insert an integer vector value into char vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

My function needs to output a value of 'a2l1p1h1a2' for an input of 'alpha'.
However, I am facing issues inserting an integer value (from integer vector) into a char vector.
Below is the code snippet. Any advice/ suggestion/ observation is very appreciated!

```
void stringCharCount(string inStr)
{
    unsigned int i = 0, j = 0, count = 0;
    vector<char> charVect;
    vector<int> charCount;
    vector<char> charnCount;

    vector<char> :: iterator itr1;
    vector<int> :: iterator itr2;
    vector<char> :: iterator itr3;

    string inpStr = inStr;

    for(i = 0; i < inpStr.length(); i++)
    {
        //Push each character of the string into the vector
        charVect.push_back(inpStr.at(i));

        // Count the number of occurrences of each character in the string
        for(j = 0 ; j < inpStr.length(); j++)
        {
            if(inpStr.at(i) == inpStr.at(j))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        charCount.push_back(count);
        count = 0; // Reset for counting the next character's count
    }

    for(itr1 = charVect.begin(), itr2 = charCount.begin(); itr1 != charVect.end(), itr2 != charCount.end(); itr1++, itr2++)
    {
        cout << "Char: " << *itr1 << " ";
        cout << "Char count: " << *itr2 << endl;
        charnCount.push_back(*itr1);
        char tempChar = static_cast<char> (*itr2);
        charnCount.push_back(tempChar);  // THIS LINE DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK!!
        cout << "Char count: " << *itr2 << endl;
    }

    for(itr3 = charnCount.begin(); itr3 != charnCount.end(); itr3++)
    {
        cout << "Char, its count: " << *itr3 << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the problem? please post a test main function

Comment: Tip: There's no need to pre-declare your iterators, and in fact doing so just confuses your code. Use `auto itr = ...` or even better, the [range-based `for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). You should also avoid introducing space into declarations where it doesn't belong. `vector<x>::iterator` is the preferred form as `::iterator` is an integral part of that type, not some modifier tacked on the end.

Comment: Hint: `'0' + n` is a super cheap "integer to character" conversion if `n` is in the range `0-9`

Comment: If you really want it to be `vector<char>`, you can convert `int` to `std::string` and push all it's elements.

Comment: Count words in a sentence, chars in a word etc - is classical example of using associative arrays like `std::map` or `std::unordereded_map`, though for 8bit char that could be overkill (it is simpler and most probably more efficient to use array with 256 elements)

Comment: @tadman I am not sure you can deduce such assumption from one example.

Comment: Thank you all, for all your inputs/ suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need `charVect` and `inpStr` to store extra copies of `inStr`.
2. Seems like `string` is better than `vector<char>` for `charnCount`, since the count may exceed 128, and it's much simpler to append to `string`. If you print `(char)1`, it will print nothing instead of `'1'`, because 1 means *start of heading* in ASCII, and `'1'` is actually 49. You have to do what @tadman said in comment, or convert it to `string` using `std::to_string`.
3. Use [ranged-based-for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of iterator. It's more clearer. It is also applicapable to `string`.
4. Use [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) instead of `push_back` for `vector`, which is faster. (But for `std::vector<int>`, there isn't any different. However, I recommend using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back` if `vector` contains other objects)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void stringCharCount(const string& inStr)
{
    vector<int> charCount;
    string charnCount;

    // I wouldn't touch the algorithm, but there is a better way to avoid  duplicated checks
    for(const auto& ch : inStr) {
        int count = 0;
        for(const auto& ch2 : inStr)
            if(ch == ch2) ++count;

        charCount.emplace_back(count); 
    }

    for(int i=0; i<inStr.length(); ++i){
        cout << "Char: " << inStr[i] << " ";
        cout << "Char count: " << charCount[i] << endl;

        charnCount += inStr[i];
        charnCount += to_string(charCount[i]);
    }


    for(const auto& ch : charnCount){
        cout << "Char, its count: " << ch << endl;
    }

    cout << charnCount << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    stringCharCount("alpha");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Use emplace_back instead of push_back for vector, which is faster." I doubt there is any difference for `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @Slava Yep. For `int`, there isn't any difference. But I wanted him to know the usage of `emplace_back`. I'll add some more

Comment: Unfortunately your statement makes expression that `emplace_back()` is always faster. That confusing and misleading. Especially when you answer about `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @Slava and 김선달, I really appreciate, your inputs! While you have provided me with clean, working code. I am still in a fix, to understand, the reason why the static typecast shouldn't work in the initial program:         '''char tempChar = static_cast<char> (*itr2);
        charnCount.emplace_back(tempChar);  // THIS LINE DOES NOT SEEM TO WORK!!'''

Comment: @Manasa I guess it's because you're printing `char`. Let's say that `tempChar` is 13, than its *carriage return* in ASCII. `string` 3 is actually 51 in ASCII code. So you have to do like what @tadman said in comment, or convert `int` to `string`.

Comment: I see your explanation.. let me try to debug and see.. Thank you @김선달 !!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest counting the characters first (using a `map` is easiest), and then building the output by using a stringstream; no back and forth insertion required:

```
std::map<char, int> counts;

for (char ch : inStr)
    ++counts[ch];

std::ostringstream out;

for (char ch : inStr)
    out << ch << counts[ch];

std::cout << out.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you @M.M, that code looks simple and elegant!